# Will hooks overthrown redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, react-hooks

I've been searching for a while about React's hooks now, and one question became persistent in my head. Will hooks overthrown redux? This is a fairly old discussion so first a little bit of context :

- [State Management with React Hooks — No Redux or Context API](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/state-management-with-react-hooks-no-redux-or-context-api-8b3035ceecf8)
- [What do Hooks mean for popular APIs like Redux connect() and React Router?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-do-hooks-mean-for-popular-apis-like-redux-connect-and-react-router)
- [redux-react-hook](https://github.com/facebookincubator/redux-react-hook)

A lot of people (React's team included) seens to think that redux and similars will just going to adapt to the new API, turning the HOC's approach obsolete, but my question is:
With custom hooks, [use reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), and a well thought logic why do I need Redux at all? I mean, isn't just more performatic to dispatch your actions to a single reducer? I've found a lot of material about it, but none of those seems to have a definitive answer (maybe because there aren't one?), so I would like to know what do you think about Redux's future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, definitely not.

I addressed this in my [Reactathon 2019 talk on "The State of Redux"](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/03/presentation-state-of-redux/).

Summarizing: hooks mostly offer ways to do the same kinds of things you could already do, like local component state and avoiding prop-drilling via context.  If that's all you were using Redux for, then you probably didn't need Redux in the first place.  But, hooks have their limitations, and there's lots of additional use cases for choosing Redux.

Also, note that we are [currently working on designing a public `useRedux()`-type hooks API for React-Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1179).

Comment: `useReducer()` isn't centralized by itself.  It's just another way of having state inside a (function) component.  You could already put all your application's state into your root `<App>` using `this.state` if you wanted to, so nothing about that is meaningfully different with `useReducer()`

Comment: Re Redux's future: don't forget too that Redux isn't just used with React - it's a framework/library agnostic state container. So even if React devs cease working with it Redux will still be available for other devs (Angular/Vue etc) to use on their projects.

Comment: I think this answer is becoming less relevant as more people learn how to combine useReducer with useContext etc....  Seems like inevitably Redux is becoming less and less relevant as well.

Comment: Not at all! Redux is still very widely used - my estimate is that it's used by around 50% of React apps.  Also, while `useReducer` + `useContext` is a nice combo, it has a lot of limitations, and solves a different set of use cases than Redux does.  See my post [Redux - Not Dead Yet!](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/03/redux-not-dead-yet/) for more details. In addition, [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) makes it easier than ever to use Redux.

Answer (score 4):

It's really hard to say at this time. The redux team is actively updating the product to include some nice features. However, one of the creators of redux (https://github.com/acdlite) seems to be on a path to destroy his old applications in favour of new features in react.

That being said, Redux is a tested and known library that a lot of people are comfortable with. I  do not believe it a bad idea to start a new project with redux Today, tomorrow, or in a year. Tech does not die overnight. if it serves a purpose it's going to live on.

However, I do think context and hooks are a great alternative to redux, but the community simply does not know how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

More than a year has passed since this question was posted.

I want to add that in my opinion Redux has lost ***some*** relevance...

2 players in my opinion have stolen a big share of Redux's position in the React market:

1. People have learned how to combine useReducer with useContext to
   implement a much simpler solution and without third party
   dependencies.  With the advantage that the React team is behind it;
   which means we will get constant improvements tightly integrated
   with the React framework.
2. MobX has been growing it's user base.  Mainly because it provides an observer pattern which requires much less boiler plate code than Redux. (This could be debated).

So even though Redux remains widely used for React projects I foresee this will be gradually ***reduced*** overtime... *- no pun intended... well may be a little bit ;) -*

Specially for green field development!